# AngularJS ui-router states with optional query params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, url-routing

Somebody knows how to create states structure with angular ui-router (AngularJS) that permits something like this:

```
1. https://urlexample.com/route?unknownParam1=1&unknownParam2=2....
2. https://urlexample.com/route
3. https://urlexample.com/route/ -> redirect to 2
```

In case with QueryParams, I don't know the names and number of params.

I want that the three URLs goes to the same state without losing the query params. And without duplicating states.

Could somebody help me?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have a **$state.go** to **toState** state in a **$stateChangeStart** event. I don't define query params in url of the states so when $**state.go** goes to state, goes to url without parameters.

Thanks !!